# Schauen oder zuschauen?

Tags: infinitive

Schauen oder zuschauen? Welches Verb ist richtig im Beispiel unten?

> 1. Ich gehe zu einem Stadion ein Fußballspiel zu schauen.
> 2. Ich gehe zu einem Stadion ein Fußballspiel zu zuschauen.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt mehrere idiomatische Varianten:

1. **etw. schauen:** Ich gehe ins Stadion, Fußball *schauen*.
2. **etw. schauen:** Ich gehe ins Stadion, um Fußball *zu schauen*.
3. **sich etw. anschauen:** Ich gehe ins Stadion, *mir* ein Fußballspiel *anschauen*.
4. **sich etw. anschauen:** Ich gehe ins Stadion, um *mir* ein Fußballspiel *anzuschauen*.
5. **bei etw. zuschauen:** Ich gehe ins Stadion, um *bei* einem Fußballspiel *zuzuschauen*.

Bei 3.–5. steht ein Spiel im Vordergrund. Zu beachten ist, dass die Varianten ohne *um … zu* eigentlich doppelte Infinitive sind (z. B. *etw. schauen gehen*). Auch Variante 5. würde ohne *um … zu* funktionieren, klänge dann aber nicht mehr idiomatisch. Darüber hinaus scheint man in einigen Regionen [*gucken* oder *sehen* anstelle von *schauen*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50311/was-ist-unterschied-zwischen-sehen-ansehen-gucken-und-schauen) zu bevorzugen.

Answer (score 2):

Das Verb *zuschauen* ist ein trennbares Verb. Das bedeutet, dass in bestimmten grammatikalischen Situationen die Vorsilbe vom Verb abgetrennt wird und ans Ende des Satzes gestellt wird:

- Präsens mit Modalverb (trennbare Verben zusammen):

  > Ich möchte **waschen.** Ich möchte **abwaschen.**
  > Ich möchte **schauen.** Ich möchte **zuschauen.**
- Präsens ohne Modalverb (trennbare Verben getrennt):

  > Ich **wasche.** Ich <del>*abwasche*</del> **wasche ab.**
  > Ich **schaue.** Ich <del>*zuschaue*</del> **schaue zu.**

Bei trennbaren Verben wandert beim erweitern Infinitiv mit *zu* das Wörtchen *zu* als Interfix ins Wort hinein, zwischen die beiden Teile des trennbaren Verbs:

> Ich möchte waschen. Ich wasche. Ich bin hier, um **zu waschen.**
> Ich möchte abwaschen. Ich wasche ab. Ich bin hier, um <del>*zu abwaschen*</del> **abzuwaschen.**
>
> Ich möchte schauen. Ich schaue. Ich bin hier, um **zu schauen.**
> Ich möchte zuschauen. Ich schaue zu. Ich bin hier, um <del>*zu zuschauen*</del> **zuzuschauen.**

*<sup>Siehe auch (auf Englisch): https://german.stackexchange.com/a/65835/1487</sup>*

Daher ist in der Variante 2 schon mal falsch, dass zwischen *zu* und *zuschauen* ein Leerzeichen steht.

Wenn wir diesen Fehler ausbessern, geht es also um:

> 1. Ich gehe zu einem Stadion ein Fußballspiel zu schauen.
> 2. Ich gehe zu einem Stadion ein Fußballspiel zuzuschauen.

---

Noch eine kleine Korrektur: Den meisten Menschen, die sich ein Fußballspiel vor Ort ansehen, genügt es nicht, nur zu einem Stadium hinzugehen. Die meisten Menschen wollen nämlich auch hineingehen. Sie sind sogar bereit dafür Geld auszugeben, denn man bekommt nur wenig vom Spiel mit, wenn man stehen bleibt, sobald man beim Stadion angekommen ist. Daher sind die beiden folgenden Sätze eine Kleinigkeit besser als die ursprünglichen. (Sie sind aber leider noch immer nicht ganz korrekt.)

> 1. Ich gehe in ein Stadion ein Fußballspiel zu schauen.
> 2. Ich gehe in ein Stadion ein Fußballspiel zuzuschauen.

Es fehlt noch das Wort *um,* und davor ein Komma:

> 1. Ich gehe in ein Stadion, um ein Fußballspiel zu schauen.
> 2. Ich gehe in ein Stadion, um ein Fußballspiel zuzuschauen.

---

Jetzt sind wir endlich so weit, die gestellte Frage zu beantworten:

Der erste Satz ist jetzt korrekt, denn man kann tatsächlich das Verb *schauen* um ein Akkusativobjekt ergänzen, das eine Aktion beschriebt, die beobachtet wird, insbesondere dann, wenn diese Aktion eine Sportveranstaltung ist:

> Ich schaue Tennis. = Ich beobachte ein Tennisspiel.
> Ich schaue Eishockey. = Ich beobachte ein Eishockeyspiel.
> Ich schaue Fußball. = Ich beobachte ein Fußballspiel.

Also:

> korrekt: **Ich gehe in ein Stadion, um ein Fußballspiel zu schauen.**

Das trifft aber auf das Verb *zuschauen* nicht zu:

> falsch: <del>Ich schaue Tennis zu.</del>

Aber man kann **bei** etwas zuschauen:

> korrekt: Ich schaue Barbara beim Kochen zu. = Ich beobachte, wie Barbara Essen zubereitet.

Daher:

> korrekt: **Ich gehe in ein Stadion, um bei einem Fußballspiel zuzuschauen.**